# How to change shell password for AWS - Bitnami Wordpress AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, bitnami

I have just created a VPS with Bitnami Wordpress AMI on Amazon Web Services.

Currently I can access the server via SSH by use of certificate. I think shell user bitnami, does not have a password, since it doesn't ask for a password at login.

I have checked bitnami documentation unfortunately couldn't find anything related to shell user password. I tried to set password via passwd command  by unfortunately get the error:

```
$passwd
Changing password for bitnami.
(current) UNIX password: 
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

I will appreciate if you can guide me how to set password for this shell user.

Answer (score 1):

The standard practice is to utilize the certificates in place of a password as they are significantly more secure. If you would like to change the password however, you will need to use the `sudo` command.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I wanted to enable password & ssh certificate together for login. This way, in case of an employee leave we can change the password

Comment: For that scenario, I would recommend using a different private key for each employee. An account can have many public/private keys associated with it. Best practice is a private key lives on only one physical device ever, as transferring them around significantly lowers the security value.